# Should I use the Guava-base-libaries at JCenter or are there other places to get modularized Guava-jars?

Tags: android, guava, jcenter

The Guava-libararies at JCenter/Maven Central come in different flavors

- either [the entire lib](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/com.google.guava%3Aguava/view) of 2205KB
- or in modules such as [guava-base](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/com.google.guava%3Aguava-base/view) of 100KB

I'm just worried that the latter apparently is not updated in five years, and has a version 'RC3'. Yet I'd like to have some place to get only portions of the Guava lib, as the entire lib is quite big and increases the build time by 3-4 seconds of my Android Gradle project (a lot of DEX'ing going on).

Should I use `guava-base` and the likes of it? Are there other alternatives (repositories)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Guava official project page](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UseGuavaInYourBuild), there are no alternatives to the one jar packaging.

I am not sure who is behind the modular jars, since they came from Maven Central in which there is no way to know who was the original publisher of the packages (that wouldn't happen if the package was published directly to Bintray).

Since there is no way to know who publishes the modules and whether they will ever be updated, I'd stick with the official release despite the downsides.